# Method does not end when it encounters "return" and it jumps to another place in that method

Tags: java, methods

While debugging I saw that in this method, when it reaches "//POINT 2" (all the values are as they should be) for some reason it ignores the "return" and goes straight to "//POINT 1". "tmp.left" is changed and values screw up. Any idea why it happens?

```
public void putSpecificNode(int index, double value, BinarySearchTree b, Node tmp, int t, int c){
    /*
    not really critical bunch of code
    */
    else{
        if(index<c){
            if(t != 1){
            t = t/2;
            c = c - t;
            if(tmp.left == null){
                tmp.left = new Node(0);
                tmp.left.index = 2*tmp.index;
            }
            tmp = tmp.left;
            putSpecificNode(index, value, b, tmp, t, c);
            }
            //POINT 1
            tmp.left = put(index, value);
            return;
        }
        else{
            if(t != 1){
                t = t/2;
                c = c + t;
                if(tmp.right == null){
                    tmp.right = new Node(0);
                    tmp.right.index = 2*tmp.index + 1;
                }
                tmp = tmp.right;
                putSpecificNode(index, value, b, tmp, t, c);
            }
            tmp.right = put(index, value);
            //POINT 2
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way that the return is "ignored" - I would look at the caller of the method - I bet it is calling your method again - maybe in a loop?

Comment: the caller calls it only once. no loop, no recursive call.

Comment: there is a recursive call, you are calling putSpecificNode inside of putSpecificNode in both blocks of your if/else - maybe that confused you?

Comment: I debugged it and watched carefully. It goes straight from point 2 to point 1, without even starting itself from the very begginging.

Comment: if you are in the if-block(index is < c) - go recursive in putSpecificNode there - happen to return in the recursive call from point 2 you will continue at point 1 from the first call - is it maybe that?

Comment: thank you, you made me see this little mistake. :) I posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

Rhayene was right, it was because of recursive call inside an "if". After that "if" there was no "else" - that's why it continued to go through the code. Works well now, here it is fixed:

```
public void putSpecificNode(int index, double value, BinarySearchTree b, Node tmp, int t, int c){
/*
not really critical bunch of code
*/
else{
    if(index<c){
        if(t != 1){
        t = t/2;
        c = c - t;
        if(tmp.left == null){
            tmp.left = new Node(0);
            tmp.left.index = 2*tmp.index;
        }
        tmp = tmp.left;
        putSpecificNode(index, value, b, tmp, t, c);
        }else{                                //ADDED ELSE
        //POINT 1
        tmp.left = put(index, value);
        return;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(t != 1){
            t = t/2;
            c = c + t;
            if(tmp.right == null){
                tmp.right = new Node(0);
                tmp.right.index = 2*tmp.index + 1;
            }
            tmp = tmp.right;
            putSpecificNode(index, value, b, tmp, t, c);
        }else{                              //ADDED ELSE
        tmp.right = put(index, value);
        //POINT 2
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

}